# Image Files, CSS and JS Files in CodeIgnitter

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I started to work with CodeIgniter today! So i got 2 simple questions!

**Question 1** There is any way to automate the way to reference images in php code, instead to writing `img/mainpage/folder.png everytime`?
Can i set a global variable with path of img files and use this in all pages? Example: `set $IMGPATH = '..\img\'.` And use something like `<img src='$IMGPATH\myimage.png'` in all pages?

**Question 2** There is any way to load my JS and CSS files just one time and let it avaliable for all pages instead to stay loading JS and CSS files on every page header?
How can i optimze my CSS and JS files using CodeIgniter and load it ONE TIME and let it avaliable for all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

You can create a class with static member that will hold the path.

```
class Path {
  public static $path = "path/to/directory";
}
```

Then in your code you can call `<img src='<?=Path::$path?>/myimage.png' />`

Question 2:

It would be possible using frames, but that's really bad idea. Better approach is using caching. If you use apache, you can enable `mod_expires` and then use something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On 
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

This means that the browser will load css and javascript files from internet only once and then it will load them from cache (which is extremely fast) for a week. After the week it will load them again from internet and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:
You can create a new config value, taken from CI's documentation just add a new value there as `$this->config->set_item('image_location', 'image folder');` and call it when displaying images with `$this->config->item('image_location');`.

I'm not 100% sure as I've not setup own config values in CI, but from the documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html the above is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

Go to `application/config/config.php` and add this in last

```
$config['image_path']='img/mainpage/';
```

So in code you can call it

```
$this->config->item('image_path');
```

or

Bind it with the view parameter(`$data`)

---

**Q2**

Create file call template in view folder.(`application/view/template.php`). And inside `template.php`

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

When you passing data from controller use this

```
$data['main_content'] = 'path/of/relevant/view';
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

And inside `header.php` load you all the CSS and JS.

Comment: I don't understand what i should do for this work. Could you explain this with more details? Sorry , but i'm completly new with codeigniter. Can you tell me in what files i should add this lines when passing data from controler? Thanks

Comment: @LucasHenriqueFreitas is this regarding first or second